# How to debug keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (and GNOME).  I want <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to create a new gnome-terminal.  I've done this before on multiple other Linux distros for decades:

```
Open keyboard shortcuts
Click on 'Custom Shortcuts'
Create a new command for gnome-terminal
Set the keyboard shortcut to alt+n
```

But now it doesn't work.  Nothing happens when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>.

How do I debug this?

Comment: "*Create a new command for gnome-terminal*" which command did you actually use?

Comment: Old question but I have to try... Did you find how to debug this? Any logs somewhere?